# Undesired scroll when drag inputs on webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, webkit, scrollto

I'm using the Jquery "ScrollTo" plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ and it works fine, but I have a trouble with webkit browsers. When I drag on an input and move the cursor outside of the container element (wich have fixed size and overflow: hidden css attribute) it moves the scroll with an undesired behavior like this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/H6PaC/53/

I can fix this disabling mousedown event like this post: [Disabling Drag Scroll for Text Inputs with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864581/disabling-drag-scroll-for-text-inputs-with-jquery) with this code:

```
$("input").mousedown(function(event){
    $(event.target).focus();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But I need to propagate de drag event for select the text inside the input (this fact is what trigger the error).

Also I tried applying -webkit-user-drag: none to inputs, but it doesn't solve the problem.

I found similar posts but any solve this issue so that if I can allow text selection inside inputs and textareas I will be satisfied.

P.S. My english is not very good, I hope I have explained clearly. Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to scroll bars appearing on the page or on a specific element?

Comment: The trouble is with a specific element. The scrollTo plugin does an animated scroll on a a div clicking on links and hidding scroll bars. If you drag an drop an input inside the div, it scrolls to unwanted positions.

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI for your drag and drop functionality?

Comment: No, drag and drop is not part of gui but, if you want to select text inside an input and you leave the limit of the box, container scrolls to an intermediate position, hidding part of the form.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand, could you show me an example of what you mean or post some code to jsfiddle?

Comment: Ok, here you have it: jsfiddle.net/H6PaC/53 If you click links all works well, but if you try to select text inside first input and drag outside the red div (in Chrome) the div scrolls.
PS: Testing the example I see that the second input works ok. The problem occurs only when de text inside the input exceeds the input size.

Comment: Seems to be a webkit only issue, still looking into a way to stop it, preferably with CSS only. the clear:both didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it:

```
$("#scroll_link").click(function(){
  //disable guilty trigger, force scroll in viewport works
  window.guilty_trigger = false;
  $("div.viewport").scrollTo($("input.goal"),800);
});

$(".guilty").on('mousedown', function(e){
    window.guilty_trigger = true;
}).on('mouseup blur', function(e){
    window.guilty_trigger = false;
});

$(".viewport").on('scroll', function(e){
  //if guilty_trigger is true, viewport should keep your position
  if ( window.guilty_trigger ) {
    $("div.viewport").scrollTo($("input.guilty"));
    return false;
  }
});​
```

Here is your update [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6PaC/87/) working...

** **edited due to @Jörn Berkefeld comment**

Since chrome 27 (as Jörn said) the Chrome browser has stopped to trigger scroll event in input elements, so I need to change this event by mousedown and mouseup+blur to simulate the desired behavior;

Comment: Awesome! I was obsessed trying to stop propagation of drag event after click and I didn't think in the scroll event. Thanks a lot! Thanks @MatthewRiches for your attention too.

Answer (score 1):

Bare-bones solution:

```
$('.container').on('mousedown', 'input', function(e){
    $(e.target).focus();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/H6PaC/74/)

This prevents scrolling – as well as proper text selection. More to come ;)

Comment: Is there a CSS way of doing this you know off?

Comment: @MatthewRiches there's no way, till now, to stopPropagation or cancel event bubbling in CSS..

Comment: That was my first solution, but Rafael's code is wonderfull ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be raised as a bug on the Webkit bug tracker.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114384

Need more people to confirm it.

I don't think preventing the mouse events is the best idea. The only way i've been able to successfully stop this from happening is by setting the scroll left and scroll top on the scroll event. Whilst there is slight jerk when the screen redraws I think this is more desirable then disabling mouse events on the input field.

```
$('body').on('scroll', '.ofhidden', function(e) {
    var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
    $el.scrollLeft(0);
    $el.scrollTop(0);
});
```